# ImportError: No module named compat

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to track user activities on my site. For that purpose I am using django-tracking2 package. But after successfully installing the django-tracking2 package, I am getting an error:

> No module name compat

My working environment: Django-1.6.4 and Python-2.7

Here is full trace-back:

[image: This is error message i am getting while hiting runserver command]

Comment: Instead of posting images of text, *post the text*. Also, You may want to upgrade to a supported version of django

Comment: Thanks @Sayse for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have hit a bug, which is fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/bruth/django-tracking2/commit/7187b22229b6565f9fc03f71e73a5129b09152ee).

There hasn't been a release since then, so you would have to try installing the master branch to get the fix.

Django 1.6 is unsupported and insecure. You should upgrade to the 1.8 long term support release or later. Django 1.7+ uses built in migrations instead of South, so you would no longer be affected by the bug.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair for your valuable suggestion.